# Appcelerator can't See The Device is iPad? What Happened?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I think the problem has occurred after iOS 11.4.

On iPad

"Ti.Platform.osname" function gives only "iphone"

How can I decide whether it is iPad or iPhone?

or at least whether it is tablet or handheld?

Comment: I just did a `Ti.API.info(Ti.Platform.osname);` on the latest sdk and ipad and its working fine

Comment: Sorry, I still get **iphone** as result. Maybe I have a different problem cause that, but I couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured that out!

Actually, I'm not sure that this is a problem but shouldn't be like this. The situation is confusing...

If you want that `Ti.Platform.osname` function to give you `ipad` as result, you should choose **iPad** as a **Deployment Target** in your tiapp.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Alloy.isHandheld` to check for handhelds. On the other hand `osname` should give the correct output, too.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using classic coding. "osname" also not working, that's the problem I mentioned in the question...

Comment: real device or simulator?

Comment: I tested it on the simulator but I thought that it may be run on the real device as it should be... and I uploaded my app to the app store; then Apple rejected it :)